# How to use Service Discovery with Spring-Cloud-Config

Tags: spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config

Reading this documentation: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_client.html

I can see how to configure Spring-Cloud-Config server to register with Eureka. What I don't see is how to configure the Spring-Cloud-Config client application to discover the Spring-Cloud-Config server via Eureka.

Is it safe to assume if I have a Spring-Boot app that needs to contact Spring-Cloud-Config server to retrieve properties, that just annotating the app with @DiscoveryClient will be enough to automatically locate the Eureka server, discover the location of Spring-Cloud-Config and retrieve properties? It seems like I would at least need to configure the client with the Spring-Cloud-Config server's service ID. But I don't see anywhere how to do that.

Answer (score 6):

You need to provide serviceId and enable config service discovery in your Spring Cloud Config Client `bootstrap.properties`.

```
# Flag to indicate that config server discovery is enabled (config server URL  will be looked up via discovery).
spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled=true

# Service id to locate config server.
spring.cloud.config.discovery.serviceId=yourConfigServiceId
```

See more in [Discovery First Bootstrap documentation.](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/2.1.0.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-config.html#discovery-first-bootstrap)